# Node Title with apostrophes not appearing correctly

Tags: nodes

I have a site with titles for events with apostrophes and other special chartacters that are not displaying properly in the node title area but are appearing correcting in menus and other views.

Example: Ricochet Duo's The Woodswoman Project should be Ricochet Duo's The Woodswoman Project

Anything with quotes and ampersands have the same problem

Comment: Are you using a token or auto node titles or a special template that doesn't run the title through the tender process correctly? I'm only guessing what the output was b/c your output looks correct above, you would have to escape the HTML entity to show it correctly to us if that is in fact what you were asking?

Comment: I am not certain why, but I changed from using the "page title" (my apologies for mixing them up in the question) in my panel to "node title" and it seems to be working just fine. thanks for your help.

Comment: Cool, page title was probably getting escaped twice and node title isn't then. Glad you have it fixed.